# wave equation solution correct?

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Consider the wave equation:

$$ \psi_{xx}-\psi_{yy}=0$$

and a family of solutions:

$$ \phi_n(x,y)=e^{\frac{1}{\log^n(x\pm y)}} $$

for $n=1,2,3, \cdot\cdot\cdot$

So adding together some solutions we also get a solution to the wave equation:

For example,

$$ \phi_1(x,y)+\phi_1(x,y). $$

And multiplying solutions we also get a solution to the wave equation:

For example,

$$ \phi_1(x,y)\phi_1(x,y). $$

> Is this correct?

Comment: why would multiplying them give solutions?

Comment: Differentiation distributes over addition: $(f + g)' = f' + g'$. This is easily proven from the definition. From that it quickly follows that if $\psi_{xx} - \psi_{yy} = 0$ and $\phi_{xx} - \phi_{yy} = 0$ then $$(\psi + \phi)_{xx} - (\psi + \phi)_{yy} = \psi_{xx} + \phi_{xx} - \psi_{yy} - \phi_{yy}\\ = (\psi_{xx} - \psi_{yy}) + (\phi_{xx} - \phi_{yy}) = 0 + 0 = 0$$ This all follows from a trail of previous results. Please tell us what similar trail led you to believe the product of two solutions would also be a solution?

Comment: I just meant that when $n=1$ the product shown is a solution, not in general